# Correct way to handle translated pages

Tags: google, canonical-url, meta-tags, multilingual

I have a page:

```
www.domain.com/contact-us
```

This page is in `en-US` language.  It is also avaliable in 3 other languages:

```
www.domain.com/de/contact-us  (German)
www.domain.com/zh-hans/contact-us  (Simplified Chinese)
www.domain.com/mas/contact-us  (Masai)
```

These translations are high quality (not automated).

On the contact us page, the following meta tags are defined:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.domain.com/contact-us" />

<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.domain.com/contact-us" />    
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://www.domain.com/contact-us" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.domain.com/de/contact-us" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-Hans" href="https://www.domain.com/zh-hans/contact-us" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="mas" href="https://www.domain.com/mas/contact-us" />
```

The meta tags are the same on each version of the page, regardless of language being viewed.

The `<html>` tag on each page is also as follows:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<html lang="de">
<html lang="zh-Hans">
<html lang="mas">
```

Is this the Google recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like the same setup as described here http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html  is it working okay for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've recently had advice on best practice for a very similar structure.

---

**Canonical:**

Canonical shouldn't be shared across languages, but used within a language. For instance, your Masai homepage would have a canonical tag of:

```
https://www.domain.com/mas
```

But the canonical for your German homepage would be:

```
https://www.domain.com/de
```

---

**x-default:**

`x-default` should be used to indicate a page allowing users to choose a language, so you shouldn't be using this (unless you have that page). This is described on the relevant Google Help page at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

> For language/country selectors or auto-redirecting homepages, you
>   should add an annotation for the hreflang value "x-default" as well

---

**html tag:**

You should obviously only have *one* html tag per page, with a `lang` attribute relevant to the current language. I'm sure you've got it set this way already, but it's not clear from your question